# How to simplify statement in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell, powershell-remoting

I have this simple `if` \ `else` statement that determines the Domain of the primary owner and secondary owner but I'm just wondering if there is a way to simplify or make it more clean.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

```
$PrimaryOwner = "example@gmail.com"
$SecondaryOwner = "example@yahoo.com"

if ($PrimaryOwner -like "*gmail*") { 
    $DomainLabel = "Gmail"
}elseif ($String -like "*Outlook*"){
    $DomainLabel = "Outlook"
}elseif ($String -like "*Live*"){
    $DomainLabel = "Live"
}elseif ($String -like "*Yahoo*"){
    $DomainLabel = "Yahoo"
}elseif ($String -like "hotmail"){
    $DomainLabel = "Hotmail"
}else{
    $DomainLabel = "Custom"
}

if ($SecondaryOwner -like "*gmail*") { 
    $AltDomainLabel = "Gmail"
}elseif ($String -like "*Outlook*"){
    $AltDomainLabel = "Outlook"
}elseif ($String -like "*Live*"){
    $AltDomainLabel = "Live"
}elseif ($String -like "*Yahoo*"){
    $AltDomainLabel = "Yahoo"
}elseif ($String -like "hotmail"){
    $AltDomainLabel = "Hotmail"
}else{
    $AltDomainLabel = "Custom"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

*Cleaner* is subjective, I think what you're doing is okay. If you want to shorten your code you could use a simple regex pattern and make use of the [`MailAddress` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress?view=net-6.0) to get the Domain part of your primary and secondary addresses. You could make would use of a [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.3) too.

```bash
function Get-DomainLabel {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [mailaddress] $Mail,

        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string[]] $StandardDomains = ('gmail', 'outlook', 'live', 'yahoo', 'hotmail')
    )

    end {
        $re = $StandardDomains.ForEach{ [regex]::Escape($_) } -join '|'

        if($Mail.Host -match $re) {
            return $Matches[0]
        }

        'Custom'
    }
}

$DomainLabel    = Get-DomainLabel "example@gmail.com"
$AltDomainLabel = Get-DomainLabel "example@yahoo.com"
```